# Has any philosopher ever argued succesfully that anything at all does not exist?

Tags: logic, existence, proof

Is it possible to prove that something does not exist? I'm asking because I find it very difficult to think of any such idea.

Comment: why on earth not? are you saying something about [induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction) or [hume](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/impossible-worlds/)? i would have downvoted, because you are a new user, and the site isn't beta: you should be looking to provide more context for your ideas. if you can't do so, then sorry, try editing it to admit your confusion :)

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. I may be misunderstanding it but here's one possible answer.

In the second-century CE the Buddhist sage Nagarjuna logically proved that nothing really exists. Here the word 'really' would mean 'metaphysically'. Nobody has ever invalidated, falsified or refuted his result. If they ever do they will have falsified the Perennial philosophy, which claims the Unity of All. We find the same argument made in Bradley's *Appearance and Reality* and in '*Laws of Form* by G.S Brown.

For a theory in which the Universe is a Unity it is necessary that 'things' do not exist independently or truly and that they are reducible.  So yes, lots of people claim that nothing really exists and a few have proved it. Usually it is considered a truth only knowable in experience but logic supports it. This would be why nobody can prove that anything exists, and why existence (as we usually think of it) is paradoxical.

It is a difficult idea, but not incomprehensible with a bit of work.

Comment: I believe that "I think, therefore I am" invalidates this argument. The fact that the question of existence can be asked implies there is an asker. Thus, the question exists and the questioner exists.

Comment: @barrycarter Your observeration helped me to understand better Nietzsche's possible objection to Descartes.

Comment: Essentially, what "I"? B. Singh has a question with a page attached from "Beyond Good and Evil". It is now in active questions.

Comment: Barinder Singh.

Comment: @barrycarter Your objection fails since the idea would be that 'I am' is real, and 'real' would not mean the same as 'exist'.

Comment: How are you distinguishing 'real' from 'exist' in this context? Do you mean physical existence of some sort?

Comment: not to derail, but for me the question might do a good job of showing the stupiidity of metaphysics. pegasus does not exist, we know that, and anyone who cah't make sense of that in their philosophical search is just being foolish

Comment: Either metaphysics is incomprehensible or existence is not what we usually think it is. The choice is ours to make. Most people choose to reject the latter idea and so they find metaphysics incomprehensible. Nagarjuna, Brown, Weyl, Bradley and their like show us how to explain existence and make sense of metaphysics. They are ignored in the faculty so metaphysics in the faculty is incomprehensible, Anybody who rejects Nagarjuna finds metaphysics incomprehensible, as is easily verified. .

Comment: @barrycarter - Good spot. Existence and Reality would not be the same thing. What is real would transcend the 'exist/not-exist' distinction. Thus, for instance, Bradley's argument for this view is titled 'Appearance and Reality', where anything that exists is an appearance.